# How to change node arrow color in tikz

Tags: tikz-arrows

So I have tried `fill=red` and `color=red` , but it's not doing the job. Fill color my node text and color color my all texts and node arrow. I need only node arrow to be colored, maybe any suggestions?

My code of node:

```
(B) edge[bend left] node[sloped, anchor=center,text=green, above] {\tiny OK} (E)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably you should assign the color to the edge rather than to the node?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `draw=green` as path option. To color node text, use `text=<color>`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node(B){};
\node[right=of B](E){};
\path(B) edge[draw=green,bend left] node[sloped, anchor=center,above] {\tiny OK} (E);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you :) Maybe you know how could I bend the line more? something like double bend left? :)

Comment: @Mantas  - Use `bend left=50`, for example, to make it more bent.